# Function to split the input expression into token units(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, token, postfix-operator, infix-operator

```
def get_token_list(expr):
    token_list_initial = expr.split(' ')
    token_list=[]
    for token in token_list_initial:
       if token in '+-/*^()':
          token_list.append(token)
       elif token == ' ':
          continue
       elif token in '0123456789':
          token=float(token)
          token=str(token)
          token_list.append(token)
    return token_list
```

There may be a space between the operator and the operand.
Both operators and operands must be returned as strings in a list.
Operand must be float.

Eg.

input: `1+2 *3/(4+5)`

output: `['1.00', '+', '2.00', '*'......]`

I am not sure what is wrong. I would really appreciate it if you taught me.

Comment: can you have multi-character tokens?  If not it makes more sense to iterate by character instead of trying to split on spaces.

Comment: What makes you think it *is* wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it using regex, take a look:

```
import re

input = "1+2 *3  (4+5)"
input = input.replace(' ','')

print([i for i in re.split('([^0-9])',input) if i != ''])
```

Hope it helps!